# Cygwin Emacs+Auctex+Evince?

Tags: emacs, auctex, cygwin

I am trying to get emacs, auctex and evince working together on Cygwin. The forward search works, but not the reverse search (Evince->Emacs). I tried in vain to find out if the emacs bundled with cygwin supports dbus to begin with, and the only semblance of answer was a discussion 5 years ago.

Is it even possible to get these working together?

On a side note, the Evince window does not allow itself to be resized at all.

My system is Windows 7 Home Professional, all cygwin (32 bit) packages have been updated to the latest version as of today. Therefore emacs is 24.5, auctex 11.88, and evince is 3.14.2. All dbus-related packages have been installed on cygwin and are up to date.

Thanks!

Comment: Dbus does not work well with Emacs on windows.  Is Evince a must?  If not, you could give [Sumatra PDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org) a try.  Forward/inverse search both work.

Comment: Thanks, I got the setup working with a dvi viewer---will try sumatra pdf. I already have sumatra on my system, will try to get it going.